# How do you open a rails application that has already been created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How do you open a Rails application that has already been created?  You obviously wouldn't use 'rails new...' so what would you use.  I come from a C++ background, looking forward to learning Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Start server with `rails server`, and access site from http://localhost:3000. Most important though, learn about ruby on rails. http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial is a good resource.

Comment: Yup, or have a look at the official guides on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: It's encouraged to use full words here, not textspeak.

Answer (score 1):

As @prakash said, if you want to start a rails application, the command is

```
rails start
```

then the point your browser at `http://localhost:3000`

Following are some good resources for you to start

[agile development with rails](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails)

[railscasts](http://railscasts.com/)

[railsguid](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

welcome to rails :D

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps:

1. Use your command prompt console and navigate to the folder where you store your projects, example: `cd C:\My_ruby_programs\my_project`
2. Go to this folder and INSIDE run your local server for `my_project` application with this command: `rails s`
3. Open your browser and type `localhost:3000`. 3000 is the default Port when using rails
4. That is all. If you want to exit your localhost, in your command promt concole press `CTRL +C` this cancells your connections.

Comment: Did you find your answer?If yes, it is a good habit to accept the answer which helped you the most. This can help other users with similar problem in screening the correct answer and you give a honour to a person who helped you.